# Why does QSceneLoader freeze the scene, and how I can run it on a thread?

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qt3d

Currently I am trying to import a scene in my Qt3D application.
The problem is, when creating an instance from QSceneLoader and setting the source's QUrl then adding it to an Entity, it freezes the application until it finishes the importing.

I tried to put it in thread like:

```
void start()
{
    qDebug() << "Thread";

    QAspectEngine* pAs = new QAspectEngine();
    pAs->registerAspect(new QRenderAspect());

    QRenderSettings *renderSettings = new QRenderSettings();
    renderSettings->setActiveFrameGraph(new Qt3DExtras::QForwardRenderer());

   // Root entity
   Qt3DCore::QEntity *sceneRoot2 = new Qt3DCore::QEntity();
   sceneRoot2->addComponent(renderSettings);

   pAs->setRootEntity(QSharedPointer<QEntity>(sceneRoot2));

   Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader *sceneLoader = new Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader();
   SceneWalker sceneWalker(sceneLoader);
   QObject::connect(sceneLoader, &Qt3DRender::QSceneLoader::statusChanged, &sceneWalker, &SceneWalker::onStatusChanged);

   sceneLoader->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("C:/Users/USER/Downloads/TreeTest.obj"));
   sceneRoot2->addComponent(sceneLoader);
}
```

This function will run when the QThread emits the started signal, but then I got this: `QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread.`

So I do not know how to import a scene in Qt3D without freezing the app, can any one help?